# When to use the dependency EXPORTED_TARGETS vs generate_messages_cpp

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, catkin, build, add-dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let's suppose pkg1 creates new services, messages, and actions.
If I want a cpp ROS node from within this pkg1 to ensure that the messages, services, and actions are all built before the cpp file is built, would I add:
add_dependencies(cpp_file_target pkg1_EXPORTED_TARGETS)
or
add_dependencies(cpp_file_target pkg1_generate_messages_cpp)?
Really, what's the difference in this case?

Additionally, if pkg2 wanted to use messages from pkg1, and find_package() included pkg1, would a dependency on ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS} be sufficient? Or would pkg2 need to depend on pkg1_generate_messages_cpp?

I wasn't able to find a clear answer within the documentation and would appreciate guidance for best practices.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/411077/when-to-use-the-dependency-exported_targets-vs-generate_messages_cpp/) by [kacaroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/128793/kacaroll/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2023-01-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2023-01-05**:
I seem to remember this has been discussed before. See #q286311, #q201227 and #q52744 for instance. The second Q&A links to relevant documentation. The third Q&A's accepted answer has a bunch of comments which go into some more detail, *and* the second answer is the preferred way of doing things "nowadays" (note: the third Q&A is from 2013).

If you could read those (and perhaps find some additional info, use Google, append `site:answers.ros.org` to your query), and things are still unclear, please update your question and explain what is unclear exactly.

Let's try to avoid duplicating discussions.

**Comment by [kacaroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/128793/kacaroll/) on 2023-01-05**:
Thanks for the tip. [This additional discussion](https://answers.ros.org/question/235035/add_dependencies_generate_messages_cpp-needed-when-depending-on-own-message-package/) along with your links answered my question:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After being pointed to the right links, found out that it is best practice to always use catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS for any pkg that depends on any ROS message, service, etc...
pkg1_EXPORTED_TARGETS is only required if pkg1 creates new messages, actions, headers, etc.. (non libs)
pkg1_generate_messages_cpp is a subset of pkg1_EXPORTED_TARGETS
catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS does NOT include messages, actions, headers, etc... from the current project

---

Originally posted by [kacaroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/128793/kacaroll/) with karma: 41 on 2023-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0